# Is it possible to run javascript "onclick" on a thing that has css set to "display: none"?

Tags: jquery, onclick

Just wondering if this was possible using like a screen reader or a text browser or something weird.

Thanks,

Billmalarky.

Comment: Do you mean is it possible for a mouse to click on the item when display: none?  Or do you mean is it possible to programmatically invoke a click on a display: none item?

Comment: Can "something weird" involve a userscript programmed to search out the element and execute whatever click handler is specified for it? Because if so, all bets are off...

Comment: if you mean this as a security issue, then people can just change the html and call the function directly, or even easier - disable or change the css, so that the element becomes visible.

Comment: I mean fire off the jquery script I have tied to the class with "onclick". IE: $(".classgoeshere").click(function(){

Comment: @Eran Zimmerman Aha, this is what I was wondering.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can invoke the onclick event with `element.onclick();`

Comment: I should rephrase the question.  Can **the user** fire off the onclick event if the class that the onclick is tied to has the styling "display: none".

Comment: @billmalarky yes, through js.  If this is security based, all the user has to do is open a js console and run that command.  There is nothing preventing a user from clicking a `display:none` element if he wants to.

Comment: Okay thanks!  It isn't security related.  It is actually a stop buffer for users to delete a comment of theirs.  I just didn't want the script (which deletes the comment) to just fire randomly if someone was using a screenreader or something.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! If it's not there you can't click on it.

However, JavaScript may be disabled on a browser. If your page doesn't work without JavaScript, you need to work on some graceful degradation.

(If I'm not understanding your question correctly and you actually *want* an element to be clickable and to occupy the same space it normally would, set its `opacity` to `0` using the various methods, or possibly `text-indent` to `-9999px` or something similar.)

Comment: I do not want a user to be able to fire off a script that is tied to a "display: none" element until the element's style is updated from display: none to display: inline.  Does this make more sense?  Does this change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, only when the element is removed, it has 0 height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Well actually I do not want the user to be able to fire off the script that is tied to the onclick element _until_ the element's style is updated from display: none to display: inline.

Comment: In that case there's no problem. You can use onclick normally

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wanting the behavior to work until display is updated to 'inline'; then this is a simple matter (with any luck!)

That is, in the code that updates the CSS property:

```
$('#myDiv').css('display','inline').click(function() {

  alert('div is clicked!');

});
```

then to negate that:

```
$('#myDiv').css('display','none').click(function() {

    return false;

});
```

Comment: I do not want a user to be able to fire off a script that is tied to a "display: none" element until the element's style is updated from display: none to display: inline. Does this make more sense? Does this change your answer?